# asp checkboxlist item not rendering correct text

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I use asp checkboxlist to have that result
[image]

But using html tag as item of the checkboxlist , asp is interpreting it as html. It works for simple text. Here is my result.

[image]

and here is the declaration and binding method

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstreponse" runat="server">  
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>

DataTable dtreponse = gq.GetRandom_Responses(Convert.ToInt32(idquest.Value));
        chkList.DataSource = dtreponse;
        chkList.DataTextField = "libelle";
        chkList.DataValueField = "id";
        chkList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `HtmlEncode` the values in the RadioButtonList.

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<html>")
```

But you are binding a datatable directly, you either must do it in the source of the DataTable or loop all rows and encode them.

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dtreponse.Rows)
        {
            row["libelle"] = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(row["libelle"].ToString());
        }

        chkList.DataSource = dtreponse;
        chkList.DataTextField = "libelle";
        chkList.DataValueField = "id";
        chkList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Your first answer works (before the edit). Need to apply System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode on all datatable rows and give it as datasource

Comment: Yes it works for me. i v'e added some code in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.HtmlEncode makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML.

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstreponse" runat="server">  </asp:CheckBoxList>

     DataTable dtreponse = gq.GetRandom_Responses(Convert.ToInt32(idquest.Value));
     chkList.DataSource = dtreponse;
     chkList.DataTextField = Server.HtmlEncode("libelle");
     chkList.DataValueField = "id";
     chkList.DataBind();
```